# Pushing Code to Bitbucket

Tags: git, terminal, command

I have been reading on a lot of peoples post about this common problem but I have no figured out a solution. However I have ran into a new problem.

[image]

```
Cloning into 'qa-lab-test-auto'...
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/lavelljackson/.ssh/id_rsa': 
remote: Counting objects: 154, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (111/111), done.
remote: Total 154 (delta 36), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (154/154), 138.20 KiB | 95.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (36/36), done.
Lavells-MacBook-Air:repos lavelljackson$ ls
qa-lab-test-auto
Lavells-MacBook-Air:qa-lab-test-auto lavelljackson$ echo "Earth's Moon" >> location.txt

//Error 
Lavells-MacBook-Air:qa-lab-test-auto lavelljackson$ echo "Autopay" 
//Posted my Autopay file
Lavells-MacBook-Air:qa-lab-test-auto lavelljackson$ >> Autopay.iml
Lavells-MacBook-Air:qa-lab-test-auto lavelljackson$
```

On the line with the Error as a comment "Autopay" is a folder. And my question is how do I push an entire folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo "Autopay"` does not print the content of the `Autopay.iml` file to std-out. It merely prints the string you pass in between the quotationmarks to std-out.

Additionally `>> Autopay.iml` basically does *nothing* to the `Autopay.iml` file. It would append anything that you would print to std-out *before* the double pipe `>>`.

I cannot reproduce that error, due to the lack of a link to the particular git repository. But regarding your question "How to push a folder", you merely have to do the following, if `test` would be the folder in your git repository that you would like to push:

```
git add test
git commit
git push <remote> <branch>
```